# Redirect to another route with React

Tags: reactjs

At the moment when user logout i'm using

```js
window.location.reload();
```

to go back to the login page but i would like to know if there is a better way to handle this ?

```js
const handleLogout = () => {
   logout();
   window.location.reload();
};
```

Comment: Yes. Use a routing/navigation module and do a ***redirect*** to the route rendering your login page. `react-router-dom` is a common solution, there are others though.

Comment: As @DrewReese said you can use `react-router-dom` library for the router, here's the doc : https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect

Comment: Please update answer to include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of *all* relevant/related code.

Answer (score 0):

`useHistory` hook  from react-router-dom will do the job :

```
const history = useHistory()

history.push("/login")
```

example here https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-kare-op595?file=/src/Home.js

Comment: With this implementation I suggest using `history.replace` to do a redirect.

Comment: I already tried but i got an error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: are you wrapping the component with `BrowserRouter`??

Comment: added example for the answer.